# Custom Metadata Type Usage Exceed but Custom Metadata Types is 0

Tags: limits, custom-metadata

Our org needs to install a package to our salesforce instance but we got an error message stating that our custom metadata type usage has been exceeded. When we look on the backend, custom metadata types reads 0, but usage says 99%.

When clicking into the usage, it shows that there are 4 installed packages using the storage space. In our sandbox, I uninstalled one of those packages but there was ZERO impact on the measurement, still reads 99%. Has anyone see this before and if you have, how was it addressed?

Thank you in advance.